# Pygame FPS problem with player movement (Python)

Tags: python, pygame, frame-rate, timedelta

When I run with 60 FPS the player moves faster than when I run at 30 FPS.
I'm using delta time and passing it to the all_sprites update, but it seems that it is not working
I have also tried to update the player it self with self.dt and it seems to work better but still there is a huge difference between frame rates

main.py:

```
import pygame as pg
from settings import *
from sprites import *
from os import path

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pg.display.set_caption("Movement")
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.load_data()
        self.running = True

    def load_data(self):
        pass

    def new(self):
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
        self.player = Player(self)
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) *.001 * FPS
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()

    def update(self):
        self.all_sprites.update(self.dt)

    def events(self):
        # Game loop - events
        for event in pg.event.get():
            # check for closing window
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                if self.playing:
                    self.playing = False
                self.running = False

    def draw(self):
        # Game loop - draw
        self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        pg.display.flip()

    def show_start_screen(self):
        pass

    def show_go_screen(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = Game() # instance of the game class
    g.show_start_screen()
    while g.running:
        g.new()
        g.show_go_screen()

    pg.quit()
```

sprites.py:

```
import pygame as pg
from settings import *
vec = pg.math.Vector2

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        self._layer = 2
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = pg.Surface((30, 40))
        self.image.fill((0, 255, 255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = vec(0, 0)
        self.pos = vec(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2)


    def limit_velocity(self, max_vel):
        self.vel.x = max(-max_vel, min(self.vel.x, max_vel))
        if abs(self.vel.x) < .01:
            self.vel.x = 0

    def update(self, dt):
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        self.horz_movement(dt, keys)


    def horz_movement(self, dt, keys):
        self.acc.x = 0
        if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
            self.acc.x += -PLAYER_ACC
        if keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
            self.acc.x += PLAYER_ACC

        self.acc.x += self.vel.x * PLAYER_FRICTION
        self.vel.x += self.acc.x * dt
        self.limit_velocity(5)

        self.pos.x += self.vel.x * dt - (self.acc.x * .5) * (dt * dt)
        self.rect.x = self.pos.x
        self.rect.y = self.pos.y

        if self.pos.x > WIDTH:
            self.pos.x = 0
```

settings.py:

```
#game settings
FPS = 30
WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 800

#player settings
PLAYER_ACC = 1.1
PLAYER_FRICTION = -.05
```

Comment: why do you use `* FPS` to calculate `self.dt` ? It changes a lot in `self.dt`. You should use `self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS)`

Comment: Furas is right. Just remove the `* FPS` part and the game speed should be constant

Answer (score 0):

In the `run()` function in main.py, change

```py
self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) *.001 * FPS
```

to either

```
self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) *.001 * 30
```

or

```
self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) *.001 * 60
```